# Различное поведение теста в Chrome и Firefox

Tags: selenium, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver, testng

Есть задание - написать простенький тест для страницы https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator
Если запускаю в Chrome данный кусок куда - все ок.
Если же делаю запуск на Firefox - получаю NoSuchFrame.
Не совсем понимаю ошибку, т.к. я переключаюсь во фрейм.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");
Webelement numberOfInstances = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
numberOfInstances.sendKeys("4");
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала дожидаться фрейма вейтом

Comment: @AlexeyR., спасибо. Теперь тест не падает с этой ошибкой. Но получил другую проблему: TypeError: can't access dead object